# Multiple items with PayPal REST API

Tags: php, json, rest, paypal

I have a dynamic order-form/shopping-cart which sends Json via ajax to PHP and then it gets proccessed via the PayPal rest api. The user can buy multiple products at once.

I basically cloned this example: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html and I got it working with hardcoded items/variables.

Some PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$items = array();
$arr_length = count($data);
for ($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++) {
   $item[$i] = new Item();
   $item[$i]->setName($data[$i]['productName'])
                 ->setCurrency($data[$i]['currency'])
                 ->setQuantity($data[$i]['quantity'])
                 ->setPrice($data[$i]['price'])
                 ->setSku(uniqid());

    $items[] = $item[$i];
}

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($items);
```

The json gets passed like that:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function(data){
              // location = data;
              console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#status").html('There is error while submit');
        }
        });
```

Here is the result of var_dump($items);

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(PayPal\Api\Item)#8 (1) {
    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Product1"
      ["currency"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      string(2) "99"
      ["sku"]=>
      string(13) "555c79be1c489"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(PayPal\Api\Item)#9 (1) {
    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Product2"
      ["currency"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(2) "21"
      ["price"]=>
      string(4) "2079"
      ["sku"]=>
      string(13) "555c79be1c4b3"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(PayPal\Api\Item)#10 (1) {
    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Product3"
      ["currency"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      string(2) "99"
      ["sku"]=>
      string(13) "555c79be1c4d2"
    }
  }
}
```

No real idea what the problem is here. When I forward the actual $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink() I get into a redirect loop.

Comment: Can you do a print on the data returned from the create() method. I think the issue is not with the input, but it is with the response you are getting back.

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   in\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php
>   on line 45

Wasnt the correct error message of course.

The error was already in the javascript part in the checkout form. The subtotal prices were incorrect and eventually didnt sum up correctly on PayPals side.